# PHP - return keep <!-- commented html line

Tags: php, return

I used return to return a complete html structure and I observed a strange thing... It remove my first commented line `<!--`. When I use echo everything is normal byt return remove the first line which is commented.

How do I keep this first commented line?

Here an example:

```
$html  = '<!-- some comments -->';
$html .= '<p>Just a paragraph</p>';
$html .= '<!-- a comment here again -->';
$html .= '<p>Again a p tag</p>';

echo $html;
// echo result
// <!-- some comments -->
// <p>Just a paragraph</p>
// <!-- a comment here again -->
// <p>Again a p tag</p>

return $html
// return result (the first commented line is automatically removed...)
// <p>Just a paragraph</p>
// <!-- a comment here again -->
// <p>Again a p tag</p>
```

I use this code in to display a shortcode for wordpress like this:

```
public function shortcode($atts, $content = null){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts));
    $html  = '<!-- some comments -->';
    $html .= '<p>Just a paragraph</p>';
    $html .= '<!-- a comment here again -->';
    $html .= '<p>Again a p tag</p>';
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: working [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6bd564f29eb49f458f69f4c964718bbdc0790257) properly

Comment: use this `return htmlentities($html);`

Comment: btw, working fine for me too.

Comment: There's no difference between the two examples, it should keep the comments in both cases. There's probably something more going on in the code you didn't post.

Comment: So I guess it comes from the shortcode functionnality of wordpress...

Comment: Indeed it might be stripping off comments. If you want to keep that in, maybe you need to use some kind of hack like a `<span>` with style set `display: none`

Comment: I can't do a such thing. I can't find in the Wordpress codex where they remove this commented lines!